# Store and use json in MSSQL with python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to upload a test JSON string to SQL Server

```
json_string = """ {
  "orderID": 42,
  "customerName": "John Smith",
  "customerPhoneN": "555-1234",
  "orderContents": [
    {
      "productID": 23,
      "productName": "keyboard",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "productID": 13,
      "productName": "mouse",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ],
  "orderCompleted": true
} """

parsed_string = json.loads(json_string) 
cursor.execute("update Table set Status = ? where Name like ? ",(json.dumps(parsed_string), "Blabla")) 
cnxn.commit()
```

How to return and work with this JSON from the database?

```
cursor.execute("""select Status from Table where Name like ?""", "Blabla") 
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

How can I print the value of the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON data type that is supported in MySQL. You can find more about it here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
s = json.dumps(DATA)
cursor.execute("update Table set Status = ? where Name like ? ",(s, "Blabla")) 

cnxn.commit()
```

and

```
cursor.execute("""select Status from Table where Name like ?""", "Blabla") 
res = cursor.fetchall()
DATA = json.loads(res[0][X])
```